# Receiving Failed to Allocate Memory Error

Tags: ruby, memory

I am doing a CodeEval problem asking to find how many ways a number can become a double square. Here's the link to the problem:

> https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/33

When I run the program from the command line it outputs the correct solution very quickly, however, I keep getting an error when I submit the program to CodeEval that reads:

> "FATAL: Failed To Allocate Memory".

I'm new to programming and not sure why this is occurring, can someone please explain this to me.

Here is my code:

```
def double_square(x)
#Create array for storing double squares
arr = []
#Make x an integer
x = x.to_i
#Solve for case 0
if x == 0 then arr << 0 end
sqrt_x = Math.sqrt(x)
sqrt_x_as_int = Math.sqrt(x).to_i
#Check if x is a perfect square, if it is add it to array with '0'
if sqrt_x/sqrt_x_as_int == 1.0
    arr << [0,x]
end
#Find squares of all numbers less than the square root of x
squares = (1..sqrt_x_as_int).map {|num| num**2}
#Create array containing the combinations of squares & if array contains x, delete it
combos = squares.combination(2).to_a.delete_if {|combo| combo.any? {|num| num == x}}
#Find the sum of each array and select the arrays whose sums are equal to x
sums = combos.map do |combo|
    sum = combo.inject(:+)
    if sum == x
        arr << combo
    end
end
#Return the amount of double squares for n
puts arr.count
end

lines = File.readlines(ARGV[0]).map {|line| line.strip}
lines[0].to_i.times {|i| double_square(lines[i+1])}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it's a problem with CodeEval's server or sandbox environment.